# Is the Book Gharib al Qur'an fi Shi'r al-'Arab / Masa'il Nafi ibn al-Azraq Trustworthy?

Tags: authenticity

I found [this book](https://shamela.ws/book/23622/28) on shamela through the arabic lexicon website [hawramani](http://arabiclexicon.hawramani.com/abdullah-ibn-abbas-gharib-al-quran-fi-shir-al-arab/) and it says this is essentially a dictionary of Quranic terminologies explained by Ibn Abbas through Q&A format. But I wanted to be sure if this Book can really be authentically traced to Nafi Ibn al Azraq / Ibn Abbas before I use it. One thing that gave made me doubtful is the version of the book on shamela speaks about Nafi ibn al azraq ( who is supposed to be the Author) in the third person :/

Is this Book authentic?

Comment: The book as far as I understand is the reports of a-Dahhakk ibn Muzahim, Sai'ds ibn Jubayr,al-Minhaal ibn 'Amr and others of the questions of Nafi'i ibn al-Azraq and the answers of ibn 'Abbas.

Comment: @Medi1Saif oh ok that explains why nafi is in 3rd person thank you . Can you please tell me where I can find a chain of the Book from Dahhak to us

Comment: After doing more research: Basically what is authentic is that Nafi'i ibn al-Azraq consulted ibn 'Abbas about specific terms in the Qur'an and wanted an evidence from Arabic poetry for each term. Reports about this questions and answers can be found in several sources but were never gathered in one book until Imam as-Suyuti gathered around 200 of them in his al-Itqaan saying that he left around 10 out. But these reports and sources vary from authentic to less reliable. For example ad-Dahhak's encounter with ibn 'Abbas is doubtful.

Comment: thank you so much. I will consult the Itqan then. Can you name me the sources in which nafi's q&a with Ibn abbas was mentioned? just book titles is enough tysm